# Is there something related to font size that has been changed in the recent update?

Tags: packages, texlive

This morning I updated my TeX Live 2022 installation, most notably the packages `latex` and `kpfonts-otf`. And all of a sudden my document, previously (by "previous" I mean "yesterday") about 105 pages, become 120 pages. It almost looks like the global option `11pt` didn't work before, but is back to normal now (I remembered that a month ago the font size seemed bigger, just like how it looks right now). Since I've also been modifying my document class these two days (but only minor adjustments), I would like to be sure if this is caused by the updated packages, or is it some mistake made by me?

Comment: sorry but how should anyone be able to say what happened if you give only so vage infos? The latex uploaded today corrected beside other your \CurrentOption bug, so perhaps that changed something.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, thank you, that should be the reason, in my document class I have `11pt .code:n = { \PassOptionsToClass { \CurrentOption } { \l__minimclass_base_class_tl } }`. This is wonderful, since I thought that it shall only be fixed by fall as Joseph Wright said once in a comment.

Comment: hm. Why don't you do `\PassOptionsToClass {11pt}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't pay much attention to this part of the code once it worked (I believe it was written 5 months ago). Do you think it would be helpful to change it by now?

Comment: I could post "we fixed the bug you reported" as an answer to "what happened" If that would be helpful:-)